# Twilio, press 1 to listen to your voicemail

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to build a voicemail inbox feature, but whenever I use twilios voicemail functionality, once the user records after the beep, the call hangs up.

Is there any way to let the user hear what they said before saving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you use the `<Record>` verb in TwiML, you should add the [attribute "action"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-action) with a URL for what to do once the recording is done. That action URL will receive a request once the recording is finished with the attributes of the recording, that is the recording URL and duration and any digits the caller pressed to end the recording.

If you return more TwiML from this action, then the call will continue and you will be able to do things like repeat the recording, like you want.

So, for example (with a pseudo templating language) your `<Record>` TwiML might be at the path `/record` and look like:

```
<Response>
  <Record action="/repeat" />
</Response>
```

Then your `/repeat` URL would look something like this:

```
<Response>
  <Say>Your message was:</Say>
  <Play>{{ recordingUrl }}</Play>
  <Gather numDigits="1" action="/choice">
    <Say>Press 1 to record the message again or press 2 to save your message</Say>
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

Then finally your `/choice` action:

```
<Response>
  {{ if Digits == '1' }}
    <Redirect>/record</Redirect>
  {{ else }}
    <Say>Thank you for your message</Say>
    <Hangup />
  {{ end }}
</Response>
```

I hope that helps! Let me know if there's any other way I can help.